# how to make text on the mat-slide-toggle

Tags: angular, typescript, mat-slider

how to put text on mat-slide-toggle like when it is true I want to show it as assigned and when false not assigned

```
<mat-slide-toggle (click)="openDialog1(element.courseId, true )" [checked]="checked">Assign All</mat-slide-toggle>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `[checked]="checked"` and use `[(ngModel)]` instead, and show html content based on the flag, like this -

```
<mat-slide-toggle (click)="openDialog1(element.courseId, true )" [(ngModel)]="checked">{{ checked ? 'assigned' : 'not assigned' }}</mat-slide-toggle>
```

Declare a flag in ts file -

```
checked: boolean;
```

Comment: need test on the toogle not after the toogle

Comment: @MDVAjaykumar360 Sorry I didn't get it, what does that mean?